# Is this on topic? If not, is there anyother SE where it is?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, off-topic

I wanted to ask the following:

> What would be the "text-book" result of governement taking on massive debt immediately before a significant recession
>
> ---
>
> Supposing, entirely hypothetically ;), that a major Western government had taken on massive future debts (by spontaneously giving away vast amounts of money) immediately before a significant recession.
>
> What would be the simplistic prediction of the impact on:
>
> - Interest Rates
> - Inflation
>
> over the following, say, 20 years?
>
> ---
>
> Obviously such situations are *incredibly* complex and there are numerous ways that the outcomes could be changed. But I want to get a feel for what the "base line" or "default" expectation might be.

I wrote it up and was about to tag it with `economics` when I saw the notes on that tag.
This definitely isn't speculative, since I'm asking about what standard expectations would be, not what will actually *happen*.

But the tag also asks that questions pertain to personal situations. I am asking in order to apply the answer to my personal situation ... but the question seems decidely not-individual to me.

Am I right in thinking this would be closed as off-topic?
And is there an alternative SE? The "Economics" one seems more like an academia space, and I'm not sure that this Q would be welcomed there?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your gut is correct, it would be closed as an economics question.

> This definitely isn't speculative, since I'm asking about what
>   standard expectations would be, not what will actually happen.

I find this assertion curious.

"'[The dismal science' is a derogatory alternative name for economics coined by the Victorian historian Thomas Carlyle in the 19th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dismal_science)." Part of the reason for the adjective is that unlike physical science which builds upon agreed facts, economics offers theories which simply fail from time to time. If there were a 'standard expectation', there would be no jokes about economists needing three hands for a typical conversation. I've seen too many examples of policies that have failed due to differing opinions.

Personally, I'd welcome pushing the boundary a bit, and letting such a question remain, with a careful monitoring of the activity. I think such questions, if kept on track, can be useful. Unfortunately, that would take a bit more effort, as it would require a change to the "on topic" guidance. I offer this last thought as a member, not a mod.

Comment: I'm no economist :) I'm aware that it's a ... fuzzy ... science. But I'd assumed that was in the sense that it had consensus models that were sometimes wrong. I think you're saying that there isn't even a consensus? In which case the answer is probably that. i.e. "In answer to your question, "what is the standard answer" ... there is none.".

Comment: Right. I don't believe there is a single answer. The best you'll find are different groups of economists forming say, 3-4, different scenario predictions, all quite different, and each one having some % subscribing to it. I hope you post this at Economics, I'd follow the answers there as I'm really curious at the response.

Comment: Your wish is granted :) https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/36772/what-would-be-the-text-book-result-of-governement-taking-on-massive-debt-immed